# Pass Through Values Using Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document schema in Mongo:

```
{ 
    "_id": "an id",
    "title": "my title",
    "muted": "true",
    "participants": [{ "userid":12345, "more": "data" }, ... ],
    "messages": [{ "message", "details " } ... { } ]
}
```

I'm trying to get an array of objects in this form:

```
[
    { 
        "_id": "an id", 
        "meta" 
        { 
            "title": "my title",
            "muted": "true",
            "participants": [12345, /* user ids only */ ],
        },
        "messages": [{ "message", "details " } ... { } ]
    }
]
```

I've got the aggregation working to generate messages and _id:

```
[
    { $match:
            {
                'participants.user_id': userId
            }
    },
    { $unwind: "$messages" },
    { $match: { 'messages.sent_at': { '$gte': new Date(date) }}},
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", messages: { $addToSet: "$messages" }}}
]
```

What is the magic I need to get the meta data?

Comment: In my solution, I change 'participants.user_id' to 'participants.userid' and removed $match because the sample document didn't have the **sent_at** filed

Comment: I updated the answer with 2 possibilities about **participants**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just matched `'participants.userid': 12345` in output "participants"

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[    
    { $match:
            {
                'participants.userid': 12345
            }
    },
    { $unwind : "$participants"},    
    { $match:
            {
                'participants.userid': 12345
            }
    },
    { $unwind: "$messages" },    
    { $group: { _id: "$_id" , muted : { $first : '$muted'}, title : { $first : '$title'}, messages: { $addToSet: "$messages" }, participants: { $addToSet: "$participants.userid" }}},
    { $project : { "messages" : "$messages" ,'meta.muted': '$muted', 'meta.title': '$title', 'meta.participants': '$participants'} },
]
).result
```

If you want all user id in `participants`, no matter what is it.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    { $match:
            {
                'participants.userid': 12345
            }
    },
    { $project : { "messages" : 1 ,"muted" : 1 , "title" : 1 , "messages" : 1 , "participants" : 1, "ids" : "$participants.userid"  } },
    { $unwind : "$participants"},    
    { $match:
            {
                'participants.userid': 12345
            }
    },
    { $unwind: "$messages" },    
    { $group: { _id: "$_id" , 
         muted : { $first : '$muted'}, title : { $first : '$title'}, 
         ids : { $first : '$ids'},
         messages: { $addToSet: "$messages" },
         participants: { $addToSet: "$participants.userid" }}},
    { $project : { "messages" : "$messages" ,'meta.muted': '$muted', 'meta.title': '$title', 'meta.participants': '$ids'} },
]
).result
```

output:

```
{
    "0" : {
        "_id" : "an id",
        "messages" : [ 
            {
                "message2" : "details2 "
            }, 
            {
                "message" : "details "
            }
        ],
        "meta" : {
            "muted" : "true",
            "title" : "my title",
            "participants" : [ 
                 12345
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue is participants is an array of an array.  How can I get around this?

Comment: I updated the answer with adding { $unwind : "$participants"},

Answer (score 0):

In the last `$group` statement, you'll need to tell Mongo what fields it should return. Currently, all that you ask it for are the `_id` and `messages` fields. Let's say that your aggregation returns three documents like this:

```
{ 
  "_id": 1111,
  "title": "my title",
  "muted": "true",
  "participants": [{ "userid":12345, "more": "data" }, ... ],
  "messages": { "message": "Foo" }
},
{ 
  "_id": 1111,
  "title": "my title",
  "muted": "true",
  "participants": [{ "userid":12345, "more": "data" }, ... ],
  "messages": { "message": "Bar" }
},
{ 
  "_id": 1111,
  "title": "my title",
  "muted": "true",
  "participants": [{ "userid":12345, "more": "data" }, ... ],
  "messages": { "message": "Baz" }
}
```

You're already asking Mongo for a list of all messages with the `$push` operator so we've got that covered. For the other fields, you *can't* do this:

```
{$group: {
  _id: "$_id", 
  title: 1,
  muted: "$muted"
}}
```

After all, how does Mongo know what to do with the three `"my title"` values? Or the three boolean values of `muted`? Make an array? Discard data? Concatenate them?

In this case, since all three values will always be the same (by definition), you could say "I don't care, just give me any one of them", "give me the second result", "give me the first" or "give me the last". The first two aren't possible, so we're left with either `$first` or `$last`:

```
{$group: {
  _id: "$_id", 
  title: {$first: "$title"},
  muted: {$first: "$muted"}
}}
```

Of course, it doesn't really matter which one you use in this case.